# processing form with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm working on a login page in asp but I'm having trouble processing a form with javascript. This happens when password and email don't match, so I want to send the user back to the login.asp page with an error message. I'm using the following script:

```
<form name="login" id="login" method="post" action="login.asp">
<input type="hidden" name="errorlogin" id="errorlogin" value="error" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
window.document.login.submit();
});
</script>
```

but my page stays white, without going back to login.asp. Tried on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Have you included the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/)? [`$(document).ready()`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) is not native.

Comment: Thank you, just did it and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the ready-block, because the script is at the end of the page. So the form exists when the script is executed. You can try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.document.login.submit();
</script>
```

Comment: That's pointless if they need to use jQuery though, I get the point but there could be other dependencies on the page we don't know about. Also let's not forget why people started using `$(document).ready()` in the first place ;-).